# Flow reducing operations expect suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I do not understand why Kotlin Flow reduce, fold functions have signature like:

```
public suspend fun <S, T : S> Flow<T>.reduce(operation: suspend (accumulator: S, value: T) -> S): S

public suspend inline fun <T, R> Flow<T>.fold(
    initial: R,
    crossinline operation: suspend (acc: R, value: T) -> R): R
```

Why does `operation` have to be suspendable? The flow itself is asynchronous, that is clear, but the reducing operation will most likely be very cheap. operation is supposed to be called only when the next value is emitted. Allowing suspension inside `operation` just opens a can of worms because both functions are supposed to accumulate values and not do something IO-heavy or long-running with them.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does operation have to be suspendable?
>
> Allowing suspension inside operation just opens a can of worms

It seems that your question conflates "must" with "may". The operation doesn't have to be suspendable, but Kotlin allows it to be. It is simply not opinionated and allows suspendable functions here just as anywhere else in the Flow API. If it didn't allow it, I'm sure there would be 100 times more users asking why, among all other operations, `reduce` was degraded to non-suspendable operations.

Anyway, the "can of worms", as you put it, doesn't seem as dangerous to me. All you're risking is performance, and you risk that in so many other ways, for example by writing blocking code instead of suspending code.